# Program failing to load image

Tags: pytorch, mnist

I am trying to convert MNIST images into tensors and when I run the program I am getting the following error. I tried to re-install PyTorch but it did not help.

```
UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: Could not find module
'C:\Users\---\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torchvision\image.pyd' 
(or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: Are you installing your dependencies with conda or pip? You might try reinstalling `torchvision` since that's the package with the warning (note: not an error), but pyd files are basically dll's so it seems like maybe something isn't being compiled... See [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/failed-to-load-image-python-extension-could-not-find-module/140278/10) for other tips.